# Best Motion Capture System to work with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My laboratory is looking for a motion capture system (mocap) to buy, like Optitrack, Vicon and Qualisys.

There are a lot of questions about which equipment is better. As I am working with ROS, I would like to know which motion capture system is best integrated with the newer frameworks (Indigo, Jade, Kinetic ...). In addition, I would like to have some opnions about the ROS users experiences with the different mocaps systens.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265175/best-motion-capture-system-to-work-with-ros/) by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on 2018-05-30**:
Did you make a decision yet? My lab is also looking to buy a mocap system to work with ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our lab, we use Vicon and it has precision in millimeters. I am not sure about the actual value of localization precision but from the experiences of our lab it is very good. We have been using vicon to get position coordinates of bot aerial and ground robots in indoor settings. However, vicon system has also been found useful in outdoor experiments too (source: [https://www.vicon.com/file/vicon/standard-2011-1.pdf]) . ROS is extensively used in our lab and we have used vicon with Indigo, Jade and Kinetic and it is found to run smoothly with all these frameworks and the configuration process is not so tedious. I have not used other motion capture systems though.

---

Originally posted by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) with karma: 40 on 2017-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1